Package enumitem's cause `Extra \endcsname` and `Missing \endcsname inserted` error while adding parameter `\label`
Reproduce the error
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{senumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[senumerate, 1]
{%
  {label=\arabic{senumeratei}.},  % Default label
  leftmargin=15pt,
  topsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt,
  partopsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{senumerate}[\label=(\alph*)]  % Change label
\item test2
\end{senumerate}

\end{document}

In Texmaker, the first compiling give
test.tex|Error|line 18|! Missing \endcsname is inserted. <to be read again>\relax \begin{senumerate}[\label=(\alph)]

Texmaker highlights the line \begin{senumerate}[\label=(\alph*)]  % Change label

Ignore this error, and compile it again. I got
   |Error|line 3|! Extra \endcsname.\@ifundefined #1->\ifcsname #1\endcsname\@ifundefin@d@i \else \@ifundefin@d... \newlabel{\endcsname }{{}{1}{}{}{}}

Texmaker highlights the line \usepackage{enumitem}

This usage was OK for compiling before, but now it is not.
Is there something I missed or something? Could anyone help? Thanks.

It should be label=... not \label=. label is a key, not a macro.

Oh my.. You are right! Thanks!

As @Alan Munn's comment, replacing \label with label fixes the issue.

Compare the following with your code:

I removed useless braces
I changed \arabic{senumeratei} with the simpler \arabic*
\label is out of place and should be label.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{senumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[senumerate, 1]{
  label=\arabic*.,  % Default label
  leftmargin=15pt,
  topsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt,
  partopsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{senumerate}[label=(\alph*)]  % Change label
\item test2
\end{senumerate}

\end{document}


